# Argo Rollout Dependency Ordering

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argo-rollouts

Is there a way to stop one Argo Rollout until another has finished or in some other way say that A is dependent on B.

For example, we have a monorepo in which you could make an update to a web UI and API in the same pull request which would trigger the CI/CD for both of those services.

This could end up in a state where the Web UI could be deployed prior to the API and the new calls would break for users. I’m not sure how to set up this dependency for progressing delivery or if there’s some script that can only promote the web app after the API has finished releasing.